# How can I display image in PHP using image link stored in MySQL database?

Tags: php

I have the image URL saved in my mySQL database.($imageid).
How can I display images using their respective id? I want to display different images attached to different blog posts,as we see in regular blogs.

Thank you.

Comment: `$pic = "<img src='".$row['row_in_question']."'>"; echo $pic;` *basically.*

Comment: Hey,thanks,the solution was simple. All the answers provided here worked.

Comment: No problemo, anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what stage you are, bit you need to query your 'table' for a single result, perhaps the ID? If the column was Imageid then you could display it like below in an array of results.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","my_db");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo '<img src="' . $row['Imageid']  . '">';
  }

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: You would store an image URL in a column named Imageid?

Comment: Is that not what the OP has stated?

Comment: Yes I stored the image URL in a column named imageid.